# how to store local storage values in <ng-multiselect-dropdown> in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

Actually I have two pages, productList page and productDetail page,
For seeing an individual product details, I have view Button for each product of product list. Like below,

```
    A    |     B    |  C   | Action
    ---------------------------
    aaa  |   bbb    | ccc  | View
    abc  |   def    | ghi  | View
```

Also I have filtration for each field in list page.  For eg for filtering the filed "A" I used normal select and For "B" I used  multiselection dropdown ,**ng-multiselect-dropdown**.

**Scenario,**

1. In list page ,if I do filtration for B it should apply.
2. Then, I am clicking view button and see the details.
3. Again coming back to list page , filtration should be there.***(concept which I am trying)***

For filteration I used normal `select` and `<ng-multiselect-dropdown>`.

**For the above concept I used local storage method.**

And its working good for `select`.

But in the case of `<ng-multiselect-dropdown>`, filteration is applying.But if I go to detail page and come back to the list page, the filteration is not applying.

1. Below is the code applied;

   ```
                 <label>Status</label>
                 <ng-multiselect-dropdown [data]="statusList" name="iorstatus" #iorstatus="ngModel"
                   [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                   (onDeSelect)="statusDeSelect($event)">
                 </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
               </div>
   ```
2. Local storage

   ```
   const testObject = {
     status: this.displayStatusList
   }
   ```

   localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

from this step: I got the selecting value in status.

3. Then I applied the method

   ```
    onInit(){
       this.getMethod()
    }

   getMethod(){
     if (localStorage.getItem('testObject')) {
       let filterObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');
       this.iorfilteroptions = JSON.parse(filterObject);
       this.iorstatus = this.iorfilteroptions.status;
       this.selectedItems= this.iorfilteroptions.status;
       this.displayStatusList = this.iorfilteroptions.status;
      } 
    }
   ```

But this is not working...Can anybody help me??

Comment: Do you have same array of object syntax inside `selectedItems` array ?

Comment: Have you got the solution ? can you please help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to set syntax of selected items array object same as data object.**

Keys of object should same.

[image]

Then add selectedItems variable in ngModel.

[image]